# Problem with the y-values of the power spectrum plotted in python

Tags: python, matlab, plot, yaxis

I have got some data and I used MATLAB to plot the power spectrum. But I struggled to translate the same instructions to Python and obtain the exact plot. The shape of the plot obtained in Python seems to be fine except that the y-values are positive for some reason!! Can anyone please tell me where I went wrong? Below, I have attached the instructions in MATLAB and python along with the two plots obtained.

```
MATLAB:                                                    
N=length(signal);
xdft = fft(signal);
xdft = xdft(1:N/2+1);
psdx=(1/(fs*N))*abs(xdft).^2;
psdx(2:end-1) = 2*psdx(2:end-1);
freq = 0:fs/N:fs/2;
plot(freq, 10*log10(psdx))

Python:
N = len(signal)
psdx = pow(np.fft.rfft(signal),2)
psdx[1:len(psdx)-1] = 2*psdx[1:len(psdx)-1]
f = np.arrange(0, (fs/2) + (1/N), fs/N)
plt.plot(f, (10*np.log10(psdx)))
plt.show()
```

Signal can be found using: https://gofile.io/d/tlJm7F/edit
Note that you need to load/read the file first

[image]

[image]

Comment: Mind sharing an example of Signal Array?

Comment: https://gofile.io/d/tlJm7F/edit

Comment: Let me know please if you figured it out

Answer (score 0):

from a quick glance, I think you are not dividing psdx by fs*N from your matlab code.
That could be the reason. I would print values of psdx in matlab and check if it matches with the python.

Comment: I doubt that this is the reason. Taking the log10 should result in negative values regardless but Python is not happy with it for some reason. Not sure if I need to change the settings or the scaling of the plot.

Answer (score 0):

I just used MATLAB code as it is without using numpy.fft.rfft function. Also fs I assumed to be equal to 120. Please change as your code wants it to be.

The plot looks like below, which to me is closer to your MATLAB code.
[image: Python Code changed as per MATLAB code]

The code is here.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
with open("./FileName2.txt","r") as FileHandle:
    Signal = FileHandle.readlines()
signal = np.array([i.rstrip("\n") for i in Signal])
fs = 120
N = len(signal)
xdft = np.fft.fft(signal)
xdft = xdft[:int(N/2)+1]
psdx=(1/(fs*N))*np.abs(xdft)**2
f = np.arange(0, (fs/2) + (1/N), fs/N)
plt.plot(f, (10*np.log10(psdx)))
plt.show()
```

Comment: thank you very much, I don't know why I used no.fft.rfft